# Permanent storage on site for important or valuable documents or reference images

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It seems that many answers are being flagged for content because they are "link-only" or single sentence with a linked document. However, some of those linked documents are of very good quality and are rather informative - to the length that no single Answer could provide such quality answers.

Shouldn't we provide permanent storage for such documents (or reference images)? I imagine a solution with some admin rights so that a user with sufficient reputation could migrate a document pointed at by an external link with a single click, and the external reference is changed to a permalink on this site.

We could have a site-wide limit on that storage so that we do not replicate half of the web here...

Comment: Sounds to me like it would run up against copyright issues.

Comment: Well, I am not talking about copyrighted content. E.g. someone in his answer posted [this link](https://www.rosco.com/litreq/catalogs/FilterFacts09.pdf) recently. This is a great PDF and there is valuable information there that should be made available permanently. 

Sometimes we might need a permission of the owner, but many of those PDFs are free for all use if they are kept intact.

Comment: Umm... why do you think that the document there isn't copyrighted? Who has the burden of confirmation? It's not going to be the user here. In any event, this is obviously something for StackExchange to say yay or nay to, but I'd be a little surprised if they went for it. However, you never know.

Comment: JoanneC: the document and its presentation is likely copyrighted.  The information within (for at least this specific case) is likely not copyrightable any more than a [recipe](http://www.copyright.gov/fls/fl122.html) (or maybe that amazon patent). It may be perfectly legitimate to copy the information and present it in a format applicable. StackExchange would likely be covered under DCMA safe harbor and has to act upon it when notified if the material was copyrighted. All that said, I'm not a lawyer. That said, I think there are places for it on Photo.SE, particularly tag wikis.

Comment: @MichaelT - I think you may want to read a bit more about copyright, it's a subject that anyone serious about photography should become acquainted with in some detail. The information within, as it is presented, is absolutely copyrighted and that's the point. Sourcing in an exact copy of the material, as suggested here, is a potential copyright risk. Also, the US is signatory to the Berne Conventions, so it's not as simple as assessing US copyright law. Long story short, it gets murky fast. Images are one kind of necessary to function well, but other document formats? Not so much. Why risk?

Comment: JoanneC: the information contained within a table of numbers or figures, or a recipe is not able to be copyrighted - there is no creative aspect to it.  A table of "this light uses this filter combination to cancel it" is the result of a calculation - just as "1+1=2" is, and likely just as (not) copyrightable.  The presentation of it, however, is.  Thus, I do not believe there is any reasonable claim of copyright on such. Screenshots, hosted copies of a pdf, yes; transcriptions of calculation results, no.

Comment: @MichaelT - Then, of course, you should feel free to present such information without verbatim archiving a document that is, in fact, a copyrighted piece of work. All of which takes us back to my original point with respect to this request which, after all, is _not_ a request to paraphrase it.

Answer (score 3):

The thing to do would be to create a tag and tag-wiki for the tag.  There is currently a [natural-lighting](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-lighting) that exists.  Creating a tag for artifical-lighting would be quite sensible.  There is also a [color-correction](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color-correction) (though no tag for color-temperature)... and once again, a tag for [color-filters](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color-filters), but little information in it.

Then, within the tag-wiki (example for [natural-lighting](https://photo.stackexchange.com/tags/natural-lighting/info)) put all of the appropriate information that needs to be distilled out of the associated documentation.  If one looks over on Stack Overflow's [java tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) or [jstl tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) you can see quite a bit of material.  There is nothing saying that similar amounts of information cannot be put in the tag wiki *here* with appropriate links to Wikipedia or other sources as appropriate.

The key point is to write the information, put it in the tag wiki, and link it when appropriate so that people are aware of it and can go there as a first source of knowledge.

The tag-wiki is one of the oft overlooked aspects of Stack Exchange.  It is a known problem that the tag wikis are [less visible and not quite 'finished'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187756/213963), but they are things that certainly be used to fill in the 'lets store necessary documentation here."

Comment: Storing documentation is an excellent use for tag wikis. Good thinking.